# Raspberry Pi as a Bluetooth-Speaker: Synchronize Volume and send Album cover to Raspberry Pi (Laptop/Phone)

Tags: raspberry-pi, bluetooth, a2dp, avrcp, bluetooth-socket

I set up my raspberry pi as a Bluetooth-Speaker to connect my mobile phone or laptop to the raspberry Pi. It works to send commands to Pause/Play the songs as well as Skipping, Receive Track length, Author, etc.

But unfortunately there are following things i did not achieve by now:

1. When i use my mobile phone (Xiaomi Mi 10 Lite), I am able to change the sound volume from my mobile phone, but only in the first 33% of the whole volume. This means if i turn the volume from my phone from 0% to around 30%, the speaker volume rises. But from 30% all the way up to 100%, the speaker volume stays the same. How can I use the full range?
2. When i use my Laptop (Windows10) and I use spotify or YouTube to play a sound, I need to change the volume directly in the Spotify App on the bottom right or in the youtube app on the bottom left. When i change the whole volume of my Windows over the Volume-Symbol on the bottom right in the taskbar, the sound volume does not change at all.
3. I would really like to transfer the Cover-Image over bluetooth to my raspberry pi. I have seen some examples but they all use the track name, etc. to grab the cover image directly from the internet over Wifi/Lan. Since my speaker is mobile, i do not want to use an internet research and I want to transfer the cover directly over bluetooth.

For the transfer of the cover image I have literally no clue. I think I need to use AVRCP-Profile but I am  really a beginner in bluetooth.

Can anyone give my some hints how I can realize what I want to do?

Thanks,

Manuel